# REGEX grabbing a number from .1-5

Tags: regex, powershell

Is there to grab any number from .1 to 5 in a string.  Here is what i have so far

```
cls
$string = "test3.832test"
$string = "test6.832test"
#$pattern = "(\d[0-5].\d{0,3})"
#EDIT TO ADD THIS NEW PATTER
$pattern - "(\d\.?\d{0,2})"
if($string -match $pattern){
    Write-Host "yay" $Matches[1]
}
```

My problem here is that this also grabs the 6.832 number as just .832.  I have two questions.  Is there a way for the whole number to fail if it is greater then .1 and also the second question is can i do something like [.1-5].  Is there a way to use decimals instead of just whole numbers to signify a range.

Also i only need up to the second decimal

Comment: what language/tool are you using (regex capabilities vary across engines)

Comment: Do you mean match the number range `.1` to  `5` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have a couple of issues with your regex currently. It does not match what you think it does.

Here's what I did in powershell:

```
$strings = @("test6.832test", "test3.832test")
$pattern = "(?<!\d|\d\.)((?!0\.0)[0-4](\.\d{1,3})?|5(\.0{1,3})?)(?!\d|\.\d)"

foreach ($string in $strings)
{
    if($string -match $pattern){
            Write-Host "yay" $Matches[1]
    }
}
```

Let's look at the regex in detail:

```
(?<!\d|\d\.)((?!0|0\.0)[0-4](\.\d{1,3})?|5(\.0{1,3})?)(?!\d|\.\d)
```

---

- `(?<!\d|\d\.)` this makes sure that before we match anything that no digit or digit-then-decimal will precede this match.
- `(?!0(?:[^.]|\.0)` means that it's not less than `0.1`
- `[0-4]` this will only match numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4. I think it gets a little more complicated if you want to match `.1` (*without the leading* `0`)
- `[0-4](\.\d{1,3})?` this matches a decimal, then 1 to 3 decimals after that. If it's not done this way you can match `0.02` for example. The question mark makes the decimal optional.
- `|5(\.0{1,3})?` this handles the upper limit of 5. This only matches 5 or 5.0 or 5.00 or 5.000
- `(?!\d|\.\d)` means that we must not match a digit or decimal-then-digit after our match. This prevents `"test0.01"` from matching just the first 0.

---

Here's [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vY7bS8/11) if you want to see it "in-action" or get a better explanation.

Comment: Your regex matches ".`1`." and ".`2`."

Comment: @sln this was done with intention but thank you for your comment.

Comment: It also matches ".`0`." No need for thanks, just pointing out problems incase the op or someone else might use this.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to somehow extract the number of the String and then to do a simple comparison on the value to filter the ones you want to keep.

If you can't extract the number, check [this page](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Regex.html).
It is a very well documented tutorial on regex.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do it with a series of alternations:

`(?<![\d.])(?:[1-4](?:\.\d*)?|5(?:\.0*)?|\.[1-9]\d*)(?![\d.])`

Explained

```
 (?<! [\d.] )                  # Not a digit nor dot behind
 (?:                           # Group, one of these
      [1-4]                         # 1-4
      (?: \. \d* )?                 # optional decimal fraction
   |                              # or,
      5                             # 5      
      (?: \. 0* )?                  # optional dot 0
   |                              # or
      \. [1-9] \d*                  # decimal fraction >= .1
 )                             # End group
 (?! [\d.] )                   # Not a digit nor dot ahead
```

Comment: I was also going to do `(?<![\d.])` but that will not allow it to match `"something something.2.0"` for example

Comment: `(?:[1-4]` should probably be `(?:[0-4]` so you can have leading 0's I would think

Comment: `(?![\d.])` won't let it match a number at the end of a sentence, for example.

Comment: @iismathwizard - Do you claim to be able to parse sentences with regular expressions ? It's never been possible, never will be. The `0-4` thing `[0-4](?: \. \d* )?` matches `0.00`. Sometimes you have to stand back from the whole thing to think of edge conditions. Since everything in the middle matches, leading zero's can be accounted for all of them with a simple `0*` before the group  `0*(?:[1-4](?:\.\d*)?|5(?:\.0*)?|\.[1-9]\d*)`

Comment: And `(?<![\d.]) but that will not allow it to match "something something.2.0"` doesn't allow it to match that at all, unless you know how to parse sentences.

Comment: good catch with 0.00, i didn't think of that for some reason. I don't quite understand your issue with my first comment. You seem fairly defensive when I was just trying to suggest some potential improvements. I know it's fairly futile to catch all possible cases, but in this case if OP had a string with a decimal before the number, your expression would avoid it.

Comment: if my first comment doesn't actually seem clear, i wasn't suggesting that you continue to use `(?<![\d.])` but change it to support the example i provided. I believe in my regex i was able to handle this by the slightly more verbose `(?<!\d|\d\.)`

Comment: @iismathwizard - `had a string with a decimal before the number, your expression would avoid it` In my regex, all possible decimal locations are accounted for. Before, in between, or after. And only one is allowed. In your scenario, which is confusing, you seem to be able to devine the decimal as a punctuation adjacent to the number. The fact is you can only make that distinction in your mind, and certainly not with regular expressions.

Comment: well to each their own. No point in trying to argue with you. You seem quite stuck in your ways.